# Nestjs unable to connect directly to database mongodb on docker container

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongoose, docker-compose, nestjs

I cannot connect to my mongodb directly to database

Unable to connect if DB uri is like this

```
DATABASE_URI=mongodb://root:toor@localhost:27017/library
```

I can connect if its like this, but it will create shcema on database "test" and I don't want that, i want to schema setup correctly on database I choose

```
DATABASE_URI=mongodb://root:toor@localhost:27017
```

Here my configuration and what I have been trying to solve this

- NestJs running on local machine (3000)
- Mongo and Mongo Express running on docker (20701/8081)

I use docker-compose.yml to run Mongo and Mongo Express

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongo-library
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=library
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/app/data/db
    networks:
      - app-network 
    restart: always

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    container_name: mongo-express-library
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ENABLE_ADMIN=true
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=root
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password
      - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME=root
      - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD=password
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_PORT=27017
    ports:
      - '8081:8081'
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    networks:
      - app-network  
    restart: always

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

I tried

- DATABASE_URI=mongodb://root:toor@localhost:27017/library
- DATABASE_URI=mongodb://root:toor@mongodb:27017/library

The log

```
[Nest] 1504  - 10/30/2023, 23:09:26   ERROR [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...
[Nest] 1504  - 10/30/2023, 23:09:50   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Authentication failed.
```

I can connect if I use

- DATABASE_URI=mongodb://localhost:27017/library

But since i want to set username and password using this approach will give error this error

```
[Nest] 20624  - 10/30/2023, 23:22:28   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Command find requires authentication
MongoServerError: Command find requires authentication
```

I've tried searching, the solution that can come is always to change localhost to my service name which is not working. Using DATABASE_URI=mongodb://root:toor@localhost:27017/library should definitely work for most case but it won't work for me somehow. I try to change username and password still unable to connect.

Comment: Are you running your NestJS server inside the docker-compose setup, or just the mongo server?

Comment: I use docker just for mongodb and mongo express, Nestjs run on my local machine

Answer (score 0):

According to your docker-compose, and the fact that your run the Nest server locally, you should use a connection URI like `mongodb://root:password@localhost:27017/library`. If you're still facing problems, I'd try to connect with a mongo shell directly with the authentication parameters being passed as well and seeing what happens there.